# GitHub上でdevelopブランチをmasterブランチにマージするやり方を教えてください。

Tags: git, github

環境
・GitHub
masterブランチ
developブランチ

・ローカル
masterブランチ
developブランチ

・サーバー
production(masterブランチ)
staging(developブランチ)

現在の状況は、developブランチをstaging環境にデプロイしました。
問題なく動きましたので、GitHubのdevelopブランチをmasterブランチにマージして、
Capistranoでproduction環境にもデプロイしたいのですが、マージのやり方がわかりません。
アドバイス頂けましたら幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Githubのwebサイト上でマージを行いたいということであれば、いったんプルリクエストを発行してマージする必要があります(ローカルで行うような直接のマージは恐らくできない)。

実際の手順としては

1. マージ対象(develop)ブランチに切り替える
2. "Compare & pull request"のボタンをクリックして差分の確認、プルリクエストを作成
3. 作成されたプルリクエストからマージを行う

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事にマージすることができました！m(_ _)m